# Creating/accessing libraries in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, import, package

I am a new netbeans user, and I'm having trouble importing user created libraries.

I created a library named "MyLibrary". I then added a folder that contains my saved projects (entitled "netbeansProjects") to the classpath, which I wrote in the netbeans IDE. Now I'm trying to import a class into a project I'm working on, but it wont allow to me to it. I'm getting the massage "Package does not exist". I would really appreciate some assistance on this problem. I searched online; I couldn't find anything.

Comment: the classpath should point directly to the jar file, not just the directory it's in.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create the library using the Netbeans Library Manager. Go to `Tools` ->`Libraries` then select the `New Library...` button and make a new Class Library. You will only be able to add jar files using this method not a Netbeans project.

To add a Netbeans project:

In the Netbeans Projects window right click on `Libraries` folder under your project, and select `Add Project...`  then navigate to the Netbeans project your would like use.
 You will have to do this for each project you would like to use.