# How to set up a new library in NetBeans PHP project?

Tags: php, netbeans, github, netbeans-8

I'm a newbie to NetBeans IDE (version 8.0.1 for PHP) and I'm trying to create a library containing the functions I'd like to use frequently (like DB connection, string manipulation and so on) so I'd be able to include it to my further projects.

The project is connected to GitHub repository and remote SFTP folder (if those notes are important).

As was described in the answer to the question [Creating/accessing libraries in netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205483/creating-accessing-libraries-in-netbeans) I tried to pick Tools ->Libraries menu item. But the button `new library` in the opening window is inactive.

I have no libraries in the Project navigation window as well. So I'm definitely doing something wrong.

Cound anyone point me why I'm not able to create a new library?

**UPDATE TO THE QUESTION**: What exactly I probably need is a tool to attach php file with library functions and classes to the project so I could just `include` it to the index.php file (or anyone needed this library).

[image]

Comment: `PHP 8.0.1` ? this is not for real :)

Comment: @user2525317 Jokes aside, please do yourself a favor and learn about Composer and Packagist, don't rely on IDE for handling such tasks.

Comment: @RoyalBg Oh! Corrected that thing )))

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk as I breafly understand the Composer is a kind of thing to extend PHP? I'm not sure that I need anything like this at least for this particular moment. I updated the original question to be more clear.

Comment: Composer enables you to create packages that could be installed from different sources (like git repository for example). This way you can have decoupled code sources and share them flawlessly between projects.